# Is it possible to open MapGIS files ( .WL, .WP & .WT ) in QGIS or other GIS?

Tags: qgis, import

We received some files from clients located in China created in a program called MapGIS. I was wondering if anybody knows how to make QGIS or any other GIS program, excluding MapGIS, open these files?

Our office currently does not own a license of MapGIS.

Each map comes with the following four file types: `.MPJ`, `.WL`, `.WP` & `.WT`.  Internet research has told the `.WL` is linework files, `.WP` is points files.

A link to the MapGIS program is here http://www.mapgis.com/index.php/index-show-tid-113.html

Comment: can you open the files in a text editor ( like notpadd++) and get a readable result?

Comment: There seems to be a plugin for FME https://www.safe.com/integrate/mapgis/

Comment: The output of the *nix program `file` on these would be interesting.

Comment: Closed for lack of feedback and test data